# How to catch RFC Connection error "timeout during accept"

Tags: c#, timeout, sap-dotnet-connector

I'm connecting to SAP from C#, through SAP .NET Connector 3.0.
From time to time, when the server has some troubles I suppose, my application returns the error:

> LOCATION SAP-Gateway on host xxx /sapgw00 
> ERROR timeout during accept

I'm not able so far to catch the error in the connection class and it is very annoying, because I'm displaying in a timer, from time to time, information read from SAP.

Any ideas how to catch it?

Here is the class that i use to connect to SAP

```
public class InMemoryDestinationConfiguration : IDestinationConfiguration
    {
        Dictionary<string, RfcConfigParameters> availableDestinations;
        RfcDestinationManager.ConfigurationChangeHandler changeHandler;

        public InMemoryDestinationConfiguration()
        {
            availableDestinations = new Dictionary<string, RfcConfigParameters>();
        }

        public RfcConfigParameters GetParameters(string destinationName)
        {
            RfcConfigParameters foundDestination;
            availableDestinations.TryGetValue(destinationName, out foundDestination);
            return foundDestination;
        }

        //our configuration supports events
        public bool ChangeEventsSupported()
        {
            return true;
        }

        public event RfcDestinationManager.ConfigurationChangeHandler ConfigurationChanged
        {
            add
            {
                changeHandler = value;
            }
            remove
            {
                //do nothing
            }
        }

        //removes the destination that is known under the given name
        public void RemoveDestination(string name)
        {
            if (name != null && availableDestinations.Remove(name))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Successfully removed destination " + name);
                Console.WriteLine("Fire deletion event for destination " + name);
                changeHandler(name, new RfcConfigurationEventArgs(RfcConfigParameters.EventType.DELETED));
            }
        }

        //allows adding or modifying a destination for a specific application server
        public void AddOrEditDestination(string name, int poolSize, string user, string password, string language, string client, string applicationServer, string systemNumber)
        {
             RfcConfigParameters parms = new RfcConfigParameters();
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Name, name);
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.AppServerHost, applicationServer);//server ip address
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SystemNumber, "00");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SystemID, "AAA"); //just a short name.
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.User, user); //SAP user name
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Password, password);//_Password);
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Client, "777");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Language, "EN");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.PoolSize, "10");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.IdleTimeout, "60");

 
            RfcConfigParameters existingConfiguration;

            //if a destination of that name existed before, we need to fire a change event
            if (availableDestinations.TryGetValue(name, out existingConfiguration))
            {
                availableDestinations[name] = parms;
                RfcConfigurationEventArgs eventArgs = new RfcConfigurationEventArgs(RfcConfigParameters.EventType.CHANGED, parms);
                changeHandler(name, eventArgs);
            }
            else
            {
                availableDestinations[name] = parms;
            }

        }
    }
```

I've tried even to verify in from the connection, by running a telnet to the port of the server and if I do not connect, to avoid getting the error message.

Here is the code for retrieving data (from a Z function module):

```
public List<clTRANSMON> GetTransMon(string plant, string project, string proces)
        {
            lsTransMon = new List<clTRANSMON>();
            clTRANSMON tp = new clTRANSMON();
            int result = RemoteTelnet();
            
        if (result == 4)
        {
            
            tp.STATUS = "OFFLINE";
            lsTransMon.Add(tp);
            return lsTransMon;
        }

        tp.STATUS = project.Trim() + " - " + proces.Trim();
        lsTransMon.Add(tp);

        RfcDestinationManager.RegisterDestinationConfiguration(objDestConfig);
        objDestConfig.AddOrEditDestination("mycon", 1, "myuser", "mypass", "EN", "777", _AppServerHost, "00");
        RfcDestination rfc = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination("mycon");
        
        if (rfc != null)
        {
            rfc.Ping();
            RfcRepository repo = rfc.Repository;
            IRfcFunction readTable;
            try
            {
                IRfcFunction rTable = repo.CreateFunction("Z_MY_FUNCTION_MODULE");
                rTable.SetValue("I_PLANT", plant);
                .... 


                rTable.Invoke(rfc);
                IRfcTable dtValues = rTable.GetTable("T_ALV");

                foreach (var dataRow in dtValues)
                {
                //get all the data


                }
         
        } catch(Exception e) {}
}

        objDestConfig.RemoveDestination("mycon");
        return lsTransMon;
}
```

Is there a way to catch the error and avoid displaying the message?
As I said, by telnet it isn't working:

```
   public int RemoteTelnet()
    {
        try
        {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(_AppServerHost, 3300);
        if (client.Connected == true)
        {
            client.Close();
            return 0;
        }
        else return 4;
    }
    catch
    {
        
        return 4;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

PS This is the part where i'm calling the method from my class, where i had a MessageBox... I've commented it out, i have to see now if the popup appears anymore

```
try
{
lstTM=mySAP.GetTransMon(lsPlant,pj,lsProces[i]);
lsTM_Total.AddRange(lstTM);
}
catch (Exception eLoad)
{
//MessageBox.Show(eLoad.Message);
}
```

Comment: SAP .NET Connector isn't meant to display anything, please clarify the point of your code which triggers this message (`rTable.Invoke(rfc);`?) and why you don't seem to catch the exceptions.

Comment: Hi Sandra, I don't know if the error is triggered by rTable.Invoke(rfc) or before, when the connection is made. The Invoke is in a try-catch, so the message doesn't come from there. Well, in the catch i have catch(Exception e) {}, i don't know if it is enough.

Comment: How is it possible to not find the concerned line by debug?

Comment: Well... I did right now something, to see if it's working. My problem is i'm not able to recreate the scenario, since this is caused by SAP server and it's happening maybe once per month or so. But i did put some break point in between and unplug my network cable, in order to see what part of my coding causes this. It appears i've missed a message box in a try catch, when i was calling the class method. Now i've commented out the message and i wait to see if the error appears anymore. I've edited the post

Comment: Thank you. Let's see when it happens again...